# CSS not being applied to XUL window HTML contents

Tags: html, css, firefox-addon, xul, background-color

I'm working on a very simple Firefox extension that will log info and dynamically append them to a basic HTML table in a XUL window.

Everything works except for the CSS styling for the HTML table.  None of them are being applied. I read somewhere to add `-moz-appearance: none;` to the CSS, but it still doesn't work.  Does anyone see what is wrong with this set of XUL and CSS files?

### XUL file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://rmtagfinder/content/log_window/log_window.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE window SYSTEM "chrome://rmtagfinder/locale/translations.dtd">

<window id="rm-tag-finder-log-window"
    title="&rmtagfinder.app.name;"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<vbox flex="1" style="overflow:auto" >

<html:table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" border="0" id="rm-tag-finder-log-window-html-table">
    <html:thead>
    <html:tr class="tbl_header">
        <html:td width="100">Time</html:td>
        <html:td width="100">Domain</html:td>
        <html:td width="200">Request Made</html:td>
        <html:td width="200">Referer</html:td>
        <html:td width="200">Decoded Info</html:td>
     </html:tr>
    </html:thead>
    <html:tbody></html:tbody>
</html:table>

</vbox>
</window>
```

### CSS file

```
@import url("chrome://global/skin/");
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

.tbl_header {
    -moz-appearance: none;
   font-weight: bolder;
   font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
   font-size: 8pt;
   color: #fcfcfc;
   background-color: #4F80AB;
}

tr {
    vertical-align: top;
}

td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working soon after, here's the solution.  I have to add in the following line to the CSS file so that it would recognize the CSS styles in the html namespace:

```
@namespace html url("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to override css styles using `!important` because when you import

`@import url("chrome://global/skin/");` it already has some css styles applied on window.